# Strange: Voip with numeric messages receives only?

Tags: voip, amazon-sns, xcode10, ios12, pushkit

I am using AWS services to send and receive Voip pushes through my app,
this thing was working all fine till last week.

Now this very strange case appeared while testing before pushing an update that pushing an **alpha numeric** message from my api responds that Voip sent successfully, but it **does not come to device**.

Then I tried checking it from AWS Console to test, a very strange thing notified, that whenever i try to send a simple **numeric** message in the raw text section, it reaches the device successfully, but whenever a alphanumeric or JSON message is attempted to sent, AWS SNS console shows no error, but Voip pushes does not reach the device.

Same changing when i made in my api it show the similar behaviour.

Can anyone tell, why this thing troubles...

Methods I am using for catching incoming push:
//->

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith iOS >= 11.0")
```

}

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {  
    print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith called  iOS < 11.0")
```

}

//<-

If any such thing makes difference: Differences since last update 
Xcode9.3 -> Xcode10
Device iOS11.3 -> iOS12

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of workaround I finally found that issue is with Region I am working with (Mumbai), when I shifted it to region N. Virginia, it works perfectly fine.

Here must be some policy updates by AWS in some specific regions.

Hope someone could save time from this observation.